# Are the functionals $\omega_{\xi_1, \xi_2}$ norm-dense in $B_0(H)?$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and for $\xi_1, \xi_2 \in H$ consider  the bounded functional
$$\omega_{\xi_1, \xi_2}: B_0(H) \to \mathbb{C}: x  \mapsto \langle x \xi_1, \xi_2\rangle$$
Is it true that
$$\overline{\operatorname{span}\{\omega_{\xi_1, \xi_2}: \xi_1, \xi_2 \in H\}}^{\|\cdot \|}= B_0(H)^*$$? I.e. can we approximate every functional on the compact operators by a linear combination of the above functionals? This is used in a proof I'm reading but I don't see why it should hold. It is unclear to me why one would even expect this to be true.

A reference or proof would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your span were not dense, there would be a non-zero linear functional $\Lambda \in B_0(H)^{**}$ vanishing on every
$\omega_{\xi_1,\xi_2}$.  However, it is well known that
$B_0(H)^{**}=B(H)$, so $\Lambda $ is in fact an operator such that
$$
  \langle \Lambda \xi _1, \xi _2\rangle =0,
  $$
for every $\xi _1$ and $\xi _2$.  Therefore $\Lambda =0$,  a contradiction.

Comment: Does this answer use the explicit formula for the identification $B(H) = B_0(H)^{**}$?

Comment: Yes it does.  To see what it is one uses that $B_0(H)^*$ is the trace class operators and both dualities are given by $$(T,S)\mapsto \text{tr}(TS).$$

Comment: Thanks! Very clear.

Comment: Unfortunately the simple fact that the $\omega_{\xi,\eta}$ separate points is not enough, as can be seen by a standard counter example in $\ell^1$.

Comment: What do you mean with your last comment?

Comment: Here is what I had in mind:  if $X$ is a Banach space,  and  $S\subseteq X'$, one says that $S$  *separates points* if $\phi(x)=0$, for all
$\phi$ in $S$, implies that $x=0$.  If $X$ is reflexive,  then the span of every separating set is dense in $X^*$,  but
that is not true in non-reflexive spaces.  A counter example is $X=\ell^1$,  and $S\subseteq \ell^\infty $ formed by the vectors
$e_n=(0,   \ldots,  0,  1,  0,  \ldots)$ with the "1" in the n.th place.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up!